# How make barmode=group type plots witha secondary axis in plotly python?

Tags: python, plotly

I tried something like

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{'secondary_y': True}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x1, y=y1), secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x2, y=y2), secondary_y=True)
```

but this seemed to overlay them on top of eachother instead of next to eachother.

Comment: please post a minimum reproducible example. Your output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the location of the secondary y-axis to prevent them from both being placed on the left. You can also use this to create a second X axis placed at the top. You can even add more, or have them at the same side, but then you will need to change the spacing (not shown here):

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(
                    title='Y-axis 2',
                    side='right',
                    overlaying='y'
                  ),

                  xaxis2 = dict(
                    title="X-axis 2",
                    overlaying='x', 
                    side='top',
                  ),

                  )
```

By the way, you don't have to use the subplots function to do this. You can specify an alternative axis inside the trace by specifying for instance " axis='y2' ".